# Visual Studio 2017 not shifting a block of code correctly

Tags: visual-studio

This has been an issue for several version of Visual Studio and I have never found a workable solution.  If I have a block of C# code like this:

```
                ThisIsTheCall(arg1,
                              arg2,
                              arg3);
```

and I select it and perform a shift-tab operation (to shift it left), the lines do not shift by the same amount.  I end up with this:

```
            ThisIsTheCall(arg1,
                            arg2,
                            arg3);
```

The arguments no longer line up.  This varies with the actual positions of the text in each line.  For example, this code shifts just fine:

```
                ThisIsTheCallxx(arg1,
                                arg2,
                                arg3);
```

to this:

```
            ThisIsTheCallxx(arg1,
                            arg2,
                            arg3);
```

All the arguments still line up.

Oddly, enough when I just do a tab operation (to shift right), the result does not have this problem.  All the code shifts by the same amount.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.5) on Windows 10 (1803).

Comment: My crystal ball says that this source file contains tabs.  Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Tabs, "Insert spaces" avoids this in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, your crystal ball was wrong in this case.  I never use tabs.  Have VS setup to insert 4 spaces for a tab and have my regular text editor setup to not only insert spaces but to replace tabs with spaces.